# How to keep a seperate div open from a css selector

Tags: css

Having such a hard time with this.
Trying to have a "Hover" event open a DIV with info underneath it.

I have that working.

However, if I have links in the DIV, how am I able to keep the DIV OPEN to click the links ?

Not sure if this is possible with CSS ? Thanks in advance.

```
.ebweather {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display:none;
}
a { color:white; }
.hovereb:hover + .ebweather {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fade 1s;
    background-color: #0D2454;
}
```

Here is the very basic jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3qk8htL7/3/

Comment: Updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3qk8htL7/4/ It seems like if there is an empty space it doesn't like it.. Anyway to work around this AND have a space ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add .ebweather:hover to your style for showing this both when div is hovered and .ebweather is hovered

```
.hovereb:hover + .ebweather, .ebweather:hover {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fade 1s;
    background-color: #0D2454;
}
```

Comment: Tried this in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qk8htL7/3/). It didn't work. (Most likely because there's as space between the elements.)

Comment: This seems to work! Let me try on my dev site! Much thanks

Comment: Ok, updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3qk8htL7/4/ 
and when I have a space - it doesn't  like it ... Anyway to work around this and HAVE an empty space ?

Comment: ** Just added a height on the "hover link" -- thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible.

Just put the `:hover` pseudo class on a shared parent.

```
.parent:hover .ebweather {
    /* .visibility: visible etc... */
}
```